# Installing additional packages Jupyter with Python 2 and 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu, docker, jupyter

I would like to use Jupyter Notebooks with both python 2 and 3. I managed to get the python 2 and 3 kernels running but the packages that are available seem to be different from my system python 2 and 3.

I am using docker to set up my environment but this should work on other Ubuntu 16.10 versions as well.

The problem is when I am using a notebook that requires additional packages, those packages are not recognized by Jupyter's kernels.

Long story short: I am looking for the best way to install both python 2 and 3 with additional packages compatible with Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
MAINTAINER Rutger Hofste <rutger.hofste@wri.org>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Python 2 and Jupyter (legacy that can run python2)
RUN apt-get install python python-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install IPython==5.0
RUN pip install jupyter

# Python 3.5.2+
RUN apt-get install python3 -y

# 8.1.2
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

# Add Kernel
RUN python3 -m pip install ipykernel
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

System installed python versions:

```
root@86e034a8e5ae:/# which python
/usr/bin/python
root@86e034a8e5ae:/# which python3
/usr/bin/python3

Jupyter kernels:
root@86e034a8e5ae:/# jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Comment: very odd, I literally tried the same code today and now it's working. I think Docker cached some commands

Comment: So apperantyly what happened is that my pip changed its target directory to python 3 after updating. Reinstalling solved the problem: RUN python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a pip virtualenv for each Python 2 and Python 3 environment you want. These might be a little fiddly to get working with Jupyter, but hopefully will be straightforward for you.

Setup your environment:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 my_py3_env
```

Get it working with Jupyter:

```
$ source my_py3_env/bin/activate
$ pip install ipykernel
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_py3_env
```

You should be able to do this with each environment you want to use. Obviously you will need to install your required packages in each environment. Also, I haven't used Docker, so you may have to modify these commands to suit.

[More info on getting virtualenv working with Jupyter.](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs)

Answer (score 0):

So apperantyly what happened is that my pip changed its target directory to python 3 after updating. You can check this by pip -V and pip3 -V

Reinstalling solved the problem: 
RUN python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip